# How to revert file in Visual Studio 2010 (reload the file from disc)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, editor, revert

I'm starting to use Visual Studio (2010) after years with Eclipse.

Every now and then I've found Eclipse's "Revert" feature pretty useful, that is, to reload the file from disk, discarding all changes. (Nothing to do with version control reverting.)

How can I do this with Visual Studio? Should be pretty simple but I haven't found it yet.

I know that I can do this with "undo until *-indicator disappears" but that's pretty impractical.

Comment: Close it without saving it, and reloading it? There is no such built-in command though, so you need to do it manually. You can probably automate the undo command or the close/reload steps through the macro system though.

Comment: This really is a version control system function. Commit frequently. You can setup a local repository.

Comment: @RobSmyth : In many cases that helps pretty much but still every now and then I miss this. And most of text editors and IDEs I've used have this kind of revert functionality.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is often VERY difficult to close the file. A single file may have several tabs open (e.g. Designer files); usually closing all of them works, but not always (e.g. Project properties). So far, the only sure way I've found is to exit Visual Studio! Surely there's a better way?

Comment: Probably you need to install something like MZ-tools for that (pretty basic) functionality

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not know of a built-in way to do this in VS other than closing the file and reopening it without saving.

There might be some extension that does this, but I am not aware of it :(

Comment: The closed file usually shows up near the top of the `File > Recent Files` menu, which you can access with `Alt+F, F, 1`.

Comment: [Bálint's new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60884004/213525) is now the correct one. The option is available _only_ in the "Open Editors" view.

Answer (score 1):

In the current version, you find in the *Explorer*, in the left sidebar. Then *Open Editors*, and right click on the file you want to revert.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using git with Visual Studio:
Solution Explorer > Right Click On File > Git > Undo Changes